# How to query records from a nested M2M field in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to understand how to get a QuerySet for a nested ManyToMany relationship in Django.  Imagine models that look something like this:

```
class Collection:
    ...fields...

class Group:
    collections = ManyToMany(Collection)

class Account:
    groups = ManyToMany(Group)
```

I can't quite figure out how to query all of the collections for a given account.

E.g. something similar to:

```
account.groups.all().values('collections')
```

But the above query gives me a generic QuerySet of just the PKs of the collections, and I'd like a CollectionQuerySet containing the full models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make reverse lookups using lowercase model names ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)).

This should give you the QuerySet you're expecting.

```py
Collection.objects.filter(group__account=account)
```

Be aware that this will likely give you duplicates (e.g. one Collection associated with multiple Groups).

Comment: IDK why I didn't think to just reverse the query, cheers.